# if function not working on my program

Tags: java

my code is trying to find same 3 letter on gene[] and print corresponding array on trait[]. but the "if functions tries to check if the whole array input is divisible by 3".. need help why my "if" function is not printing!!!

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //args example: TTTGGTGGGTTC     

        String[] gene = {"TTT","TTC"........GGC","GGA","GGG"};
        char[] trait = {'F','F','V','V'......,'E','G','G','G','G'};

        String input = args[0];
        int dome = input.length();
        int x = 0;
        int z = 2;
        int b = 0;



        for (int c = 0 ; c <= dome/3 ; c++){
            String top = input.substring(x, z+1);
            while (!top.equals(gene[b]) ){
                b = b + 1;
            }
            System.out.print(trait[b] + " ");
            x = x + 3;
            z = z + 3;
            b = 0;
        }   
        if ( dome%3 == 0){
            System.out.print("no excess ");
        }else{
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What input are you giving your program on the command line? I want to know what input becomes after `String input = args[0];`. Also, your c variable is never used.

Comment: Not sure what it's trying to accomplish; do you actually want that inside your loop and base it on the value of `c`?

Comment: What is your expected output, what is the given output? With the example string given, it should print "no excess", because `input`'s length (12) *is* dividable by 3

Comment: Maybe declare `c` outside of the for loop, so it's still in scope when you check `if(c%3==0)`

Comment: example input in command line is :TTTGGCGGGTTC
then out put would be : F E G F
but if your input is :TTTGGCGGGTT //1char missing
output would be : F E G *

Comment: @Gus Where do you see `if(c%3==0)`?

Comment: The mapping of genes to traits could be done far more efficiently with a map.

Comment: @BryanJamesLim And what actually happens when you give it an input of length 11? We know what is _supposed_ to happen but apparently the problem is that it _doesn't_ happen. So, tell us what _does_ happen.

Comment: @DavidConrad it's not there, but it should replace `if(dome%3==0)`

Comment: Is it giving you an exception/error message when you run it?

Comment: @Gus No, it shouldn't. The test is whether the length of the input is divisible by 3, and `dome` contains the length of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your for loop runs one index too many. Instead of

```
for (int c = 0 ; c <= dome/3 ; c++)
```

try

```
for (int c = 0 ; c < dome/3 ; c++)
```

Comment: The problem is with the if statement and the loop changes nothing in respect to the if statement.

Comment: @Takendarkk It has quite a lot to do with the if statement. If the length is divisible by 3, then the last iteration of the loop will throw an `IndexOutOfBounds` on the `substring` because of the extra iteration, hence the program would never reach said `if`. Given the epic skill of the OP with datastructures, I wouldn't be surprised if they just ignored an exception being thrown.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is what is happening. (Tested and confirmed.)

Answer (score 0):

If your if/else part is not working then,there might be an exception is thrown from inside For loop.

Because the for loop updates nothing,by which the if/else part are affected.